# What key do I press to turn on "Extra Lights" on ETS2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

There are these **Light Bars** and **Lights** you can put on them, but I can't figure out how to turn them On pressing a Key on the Keyboard on ETS2 *(Euro Truck Simulator 2)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to press the F4 Key to enter in the light adjustment menu.

Answer (score 0):

On my game I've found that 'o' is the game default for beacons

Comment: Is it O on a PS Controller? Or o as the keyboard's o?

Comment: The letter "o" on the keyboard toggles the beacons.